# readPixels: buffer is not large enough for dimensions

Tags: javascript, webgl, textures

I get the following error in Chrome:

> WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: readPixels: buffer is not large enough for
> dimensions

when trying to read the pixels of the first layer of a array texture with this code:

```
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, this._texture)
    const readFbo = gl.createFramebuffer()
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.READ_FRAMEBUFFER, readFbo)
    gl.framebufferTextureLayer(gl.READ_FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, this._texture, 0, 0)
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(this._width * this._height)
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, this._width, this._height, gl.RED, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer)
```

when this._width=3021 and this._height=2843. However it works fine when this._width=this._height=512.
I don't understand how my buffer can be too small (and only when certain dimensions are used).

Any ideas what's causing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the `PACK_ALIGNMENT` parameter. By default, this parameter is set to 4, which means that the size of each row of pixels is aligned to 4 bytes. This results in the image is not tightly packed and takes more space than you expect. Since the width of your image is not divisible by 4 (width=3021), the alignment must be set to 1 (before `gl.readPixels`):

```js
gl.pixelStorei(gl.PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

Comment: thank you very much ! though there is some inconsistency in your answer (UNPACK_ALIGNMENT vs PACK_ALIGNMENT in code). does that mean the same applies for texSubImage3D vs (UN)PACK_ALIGNMENT ?

Comment: @Lenny thank's. `PACK_ALIGNMENT` is for reading texture images from the GPU and `UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` is for transferring images to the GPU.